# Mongodb: Unset Field from Document?

Tags: mongodb, unset

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
    {
        "description" : "details of student",
        "displayGroup" : "",
        "role" : [
            {
                "name" : "admin",
                "edit" : "no"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp" : "2015-09-01 15:29:09"
    },
"subject" : {
        "class" : "Fifth",
        "description" : "5th class",
        "displayGroup" : "section A",
        "timestamp" : "2015-09-01 15:29:09"
    }
    }
```

This data i have,And i want to remove Subjet Array from my document where Class =5How can i remove?

i run this below Query:-

```
db.collectionName.update({"subject.class":"Fifth"},{$unset:{subject:""}})
```

But this is giving 1 Match no modification.
i want to remove this from my document in one shot.Help me out?

Comment: `5 != Fifth`. How did you even get 1 match? Yes because you have another document with `Fifth` inside there.

Comment: Ohh my mistake..Edited.

Comment: Is that even a valid document? What's the missing field for the subdocument just after the `_id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following document (had to add `person` attribute because it was not valid).

```
> db.coll.findOne({"subject.class": "Fifth"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
    "person" : {
        "description" : "details of student",
        "displayGroup" : "",
        "role" : [
            {
                "name" : "admin",
                "edit" : "no"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp" : "2015-09-01 15:29:09"
    },
    "subject" : {
        "class" : "Fifth",
        "description" : "5th class",
        "displayGroup" : "section A",
        "timestamp" : "2015-09-01 15:29:09"
    }
}
```

When you use [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) on `subject` the document is matched and modified. Using [update's multi option](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/) you can instruct mongo to update all the documents that match the query.

```
> db.coll.update({"subject.class": "Fifth"}, {$unset: {subject: ""}}, {multi: true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Given `subject` was removed querying on `subject.class` is no longer possible.

Querying by `_id` you can see that the field was removed from the document.

```
> db.coll.findOne({_id: ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781")})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d6cb28725f3019a5241781"),
    "person" : {
        "description" : "details of student",
        "displayGroup" : "",
        "role" : [
            {
                "name" : "admin",
                "edit" : "no"
            }
        ],
        "timestamp" : "2015-09-01 15:29:09"
    }
}
```

Comment: no but i want to remove from all documents..there are multiple documents are there.

Comment: @NehaB in that case you should use the `multi` option https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/ I have update my answer to include the option.